# Style based on Enum value

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an enum as follows:

```
 enum ProgressStatus{
   Approved,
   Unapproved,
   InProcess
 }
```

I have an `Project` object that use this class. Based on the enum values I need to show their values as Green, Yellow or Blue in while styling.

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
      @if (Model.ProgressStatus == ProgressStatus.Approved)
      {
        <li style="color:red;"><label>Vaziyet Planı</label></li>
      }

</ol>
```

This is how i try to do it but it get cumbersome and clumsy.

What is the correct way to get this done?

Comment: Define a CSS Class `Approved {color: red}` & `<li class="Approved" ` ?

Comment: That s not a problem, i dont want to do 3 if statements.

Comment: @DarthVader Alex K's solution is fine. I assume he meant `<li class="@Model.ProgressStatus"` to set the class. Then define the three colours in your CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with your enum, you can use a short switch to set the color:

```
@{
    string color;
    switch(Model.ProgressStatus)
    { 
         case ProgressStatus.Approved : color = "green"; break; 
         case ProgressStatus.Unapproved : color = "yellow"; break; 
         //...
    }
 }
```

then you only need the one element

```
 <li style="color:@color;"><label>Vaziyet Planı</label></li>
```

This is just a different take on Stijn's answer really.  I like his better.

Comment: Yours is fine when there's only one label, mine is more useful when looping over a collection. +1

Comment: I have tried to use this example but I was getting a compilation error on color: (at)color. The solution is to declare string color = ""; to have a declared value before (at)color get used and avoid the error

Answer (score 4):

Put this in your view:

```
@{

    var labelColours = new Dictionary<ProgressStatus, string>()
    {
        { ProgressStatus.Approved, "green" },
        { ProgressStatus.Unapproved, "yellow" },
        { ProgressStatus.InProcess, "blue" }
    };
}
```

Then use this in your label:

```
<li style="color: @labelColours[Model.ProgressStatus];">
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this logic in the controller and resolve it to a single model property that you bind to the view.

```
<li class='@Model.FinalStyle'><label>@Model.Text</label></li>
```

Comment: I can do that, but then why would i write css  style in logic code.

Comment: IMO the view model is there to serve all needs of the view, whether it be data or look and feel. It might be prettier to make it a class instead of a style attribute.

Comment: @Stijn IMO it's better and much more testable to have the logic in the controller. It's really no different than resolving a calculation in the controller and displaying a different numeric value based on various conditions.

Comment: But that goes against the whole point of MVC: to separate these things.

Comment: There is still clear separation. It comes down to resolving data needed by the view. The controller is still not tied to the view. It just knows how to return data. How the data is used is still up to the view

Comment: I respectfully disagree, if the controller is deciding how the view should represent a certain resource, you're breaking separation. I'm also curious how you test that your UI renders correctly by testing the controller. The controller may set the correct colour, but that doesn't guarantee that your view is correct.

Comment: The testing applies to the logic in the controller not the view. It only knows that for a given condition is should return a certain string. It doesn't even know that it's consumed by a view or how it will be used.